# How to copy a range (it is a table A9 to G30) from one worksheet (student#1) to all other 23 sheets (upto student # 24)

Tags: excel, vba

What is the code to copy a range (it is a table from A9 to G30) from one worksheet called (student#1) to all other 23 sheets (upto sheet student#24), without loosing the format. If some one can help me please, I am totally new to VBA.

Comment: Welcome! It sounds like `Range.Copy` will do the trick here, this is an MSDN article on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I want to copy this into all other 23 sheets without loosing the format. The above MSDN article shows example to copy to another sheet (whereas I want to copy to all other 23 sheets). Any clue Dan?

Comment: You can use the `Worksheets` collection object for that loop. I'll put in a short note in an answer momentarily

Comment: If an answer suits you, please accept it at your convenience. Here's a super-quick explanation in the form of a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I might address this:

```
Sub CoolStuff()

'set the start sheet and range up-front
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("student#1")
Set MyRange = MySheet.Range("A9:G30")

'loop through all sheets and paste your range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ra As Range
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "student#1"
        Set ra = ws.Range("A9:G30")
        MyRange.Copy ra
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a range from one worksheet to multiple sheets in one operation.  You do not need a loop.  Here is an example:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A9:G30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Use your own worksheet names and expand this line:

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
```

to suit your needs

Comment: +1 love it, definitely a great way to take this one too. SO is a **CONSTANT** reminder that there are many ways to solve the same problem...

Comment: @DanWagner  Thank you......there is a similar trick that can be used to print multiple sheets with one command.

Comment: Dear Gary's Student can you add more sheets in the code or how do I write the code if it is upto sheet24.  Thans for all your help

Comment: Note to aspiring VBA folks: pay attention to @Gary'sStudent answers to learn about a way you hadn't considered before haha

Comment: @AhmedSayeedKhan  My solution runs rapidly, however, if the number of students was very large, then **I** would use Dan's solution instead!

Answer (score 0):

I like @Dan Wagner's solution, but I would do things just a little differently. By saving the value you want to copy as a variable, you only have to look it up once. And you can optimize just a little more by starting at the second sheet. This prevents having to evaluate an `if` statement for each sheet.

```
Sub CopyRangeToAllSheets()

    Dim x()
    x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A9:G30").Value

    Dim n As Long
    For n = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Range("A9:G30").Value = x
    Next n

End Sub
```